# Ember: new project contains old dependencies

Tags: ember.js

**Environment**

- Mac OS X 10.10.5
- NodeJS 4.2.4

**Globally installed NPM Packages**:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
├── bower@1.7.2
├── ember-cli@1.13.13
└── npm@3.5.3
```

**Create new Ember project**:

```
ember new super-rentals
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "super-rentals",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.13.11",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.16",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
    "qunit": "~1.20.0"
  }
}
```

Question

- why did Ember create a bower.json file containing old dependencies? For example, today the latest Ember version is 2.2.0. Ember installed version 1.13.11.

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable version of ember-cli is 1.13.13, which points to the latest Ember 1.13.x as part of the plan of "lockstep versioning". Unfortunately, ember-cli 2.x has been delayed, and is still in beta. So you have two choices:

1. Use ember-cli 2.2beta3, which will install the latest dependencies or,
2. Use ember-cli 1.13.13, and manually update the dependencies by editing bower.json and package.json.

**Update**: ember-cli 2.3.0 final has been released. Use that.